# Android intent to other Activity carry string not working

Tags: android, android-intent

I have one question about intent another Activity and carry String.

I refer "DeviceScanActivity" sample code , I find this one :

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, DeviceControlActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(DeviceControlActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS,device.getAddress()); 
startActivity(intent);
```

then in "DeviceControlActivity" sample code , I find this :

```
final Intent intent = getIntent();
mDeviceAddress = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
```

mDeviceAddress will get String from DeviceScanActivity.

now I want to intent another Activity from DeviceControlActivity to NewActivity,
so in DeviceControlActivity , I do this :

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(NewActivity.DEVICE_ADDRESS, EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
startActivity(intent);
```

and in NewActivity , I do this :

```
final Intent intent = getIntent();
address = intent.getStringExtra(DEVICE_ADDRESS);
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.p1_device_address)).setText(address);
```

but in NewActivity , all I can see is "DEVICE_ADDRESS" ?

not really address like : B0:B4:48:BD:69:85

I want to know why , anyone can help me , I would be very grateful , Tnanks.

Comment: "but in NewActivity , all I can see is "DEVICE_ADDRESS" ?" - Because that's what you're putting on the `Intent` – `intent.putExtra(NewActivity.DEVICE_ADDRESS, EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS);`. Don't you want to put `mDeviceAddress` there, instead of `EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS`?

Comment: Thanks Mike M , my question is resolve . Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. You can probably just delete this, then, since it was just a variable mix-up; basically a typo. Cheers!